# No data in Sitecore Experience profile

Tags: sitecore

I've set up a local Sitecore environment with all sql and mongodb db's working.

Except i do not get any data in the experience profile (contacts)

I see that tracking_contact db is empty in mongo and also the analytics index folder is empty.

Other functionalities like experience analytics work fine.

Are there any extra configurations necessary?

Comment: Can you see any errors in the logs?

Comment: Have you got any entries in the interactions collection in MongoDb? If you have then it should all be working. Remember that the data while browsing is in the shared session and will get flushed into MongoDb on session end.

Answer (score 2):

The Experience Profile runs on the Analytics index. If there is no index, there will be no data shown.
Try to rebuild the index if it's not there.

There is an admin tool for rebuilding the reporting db & analytics index: `/sitecore/admin/RebuildReportingDB.aspx`

When you run the tool you must setup a secondary reporting db first.
Just attach another empty analtyics database to your local SQL and name it something like `analytics_secondary` and configure its connectionstring.
Then rebuild the reporting db and after that data should appear in your Experience Profile.

The index should be constantly refreshed by the aggregation framework (i.e. you should not need to rebuild) so if that is not happening, something is wrong in your configuration.

Answer (score 1):

When working with xDB you'll need to identify a user to get it to appear in the experience profile section  otherwise they will be anonymous.

Try using this code here to create a contact:

https://github.com/ianjohngraham/CoreBlimey.Utils/tree/master/CoreBlimey.Utils/xDB%20Contact%20Creator

And then call the end session by using the button.

If everything is setup correctly then the contact you created will appear in MongoDB and in Experience Profile.

If you are still not getting any data then you could try these things:

1. Ensure you have the `<sc:VisitorIdentification runat="server" />` control for asp web forms layout
   the `@Html.Sitecore().VisitorIdentification()` control for MVC layout
2. Make sure you disable robot detection by changing this setting `<setting name="Analytics.AutoDetectBots" />`

Answer (score 0):

Charley,

I also had the similar problem in past, so what I found was, it was not working in my local, but when i put it stage server it shows data to me. So same may apply to you also.

Also without "@Html.Sitecore().VisitorIdentification()" in your Layout tracking is not possible.

Hope this will help you.

cheers!!